# How to load google ads from ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, adsense

This question was asked many times.
I have seen discussion everywhere.
But i cant find a recent discussion about this.

First of all, **is it allowed or not?**
I run a site with full of ajax.
So, for the first time i load a ad and it never changes.

I am not getting the benefit of google ads now.
If possible how can i load it?

I am using **jquery**

Can i use `$.ajax.load('adsense.html')`?
Will it work?

Comment: To my knowledge, that's not allowed. There was [a beta program](https://developers.google.com/adsense-for-ajax/) for AJAX ads, but it's over and I haven't heard of any of it being implemented in mainline AdSense. [This may be an approach you can take](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7925142).

Comment: Didn't expect this. Ajax is beauty. Everyone likes ajax. I thought there would be a legal solution for this :(